# geting index of member of a vector which has been constructed based on the other vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, stl, boost-variant

Let's Say I have a std::vector< boost::variant< T1, T2, T3> >, e.g.
note that in my vector it is an obligation to have two 'b' **or** one 'q' after 'a'.

note that these 'a', 'b' and 'q' are different, and you do not know about the way they mix.

```
std::vector< boost::variant< T1, T2, T3> > vec; 
vec = {a, b, b, a, q, a, q, a, b, b, a, q}
```

thanks to the boost visitor, nOw I've filtered each element type (T) separately:

```
veca= {a, a, a, a, a}
vecb= {b, b, b, b}
vecq= {q, q, q}
```

now I want to loop over 'vecq' and for each member find the index in the 'vec' vector and then by finding this index, I am able to find the Index of the 'a' behind this 'q' in 'vec' and finally find the index of 'a' in 'veca'.

I know it's spiry question, I am looking for a simple way (faster than iterating throught the vectors).

P.S. I am using c++98 standard

**EDIT:**

The visitor I used

```
template<typename T>
struct T_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
   T_visitor(std::vector<T>& v) : vec(v) {}
   template<typename U>
   void operator () (const U&) {}
   void operator () (const T& value)
   {
      vec.push_back(value);
   }
private:
   std::vector<T>& vec;
};
```

**Second EDIT:**

in other word:
Let's Say I have a std::vector< boost::variant< T1, T2, T3> >, e.g.

```
std::vector< boost::variant< T1, T2, T3> > vec; 
vec = {a1, b15, b1, a5, q0, a5, q1, a9, b7, b6, a4, q2}
```

note that these 'a', 'b' and 'q' are different, and you do not know about the way they mix. the only thing you knowis that in my vector it is an obligation to have two **'b'** **or** one **'q'** after **'a'**.
When I call my function I know that I receive a vector which has been constructed similar to vec. then I have two functions which gets as input "T1, T3" and "T1, T2".

for e.g. gets (a1, b15,b1) **or** (a5, q0) **or** (a5, q1) **or** (a9, b7,b6) **or**..

but I dont know how to give them these inputs.

Comment: Why you need filtration and not one pass through variants vector by some visitor, that can check invariants?

Comment: Yes, and if you do what ForEveR said, but scanning the vector _backward_ (starting from the end, e.g. using a reverse iterator), you can easily remember the position of the most recent `a`, which will tell you, once you found a `q`, what the next `a` is that follows it.

Comment: @ thanks for your comments, but I need these vectors,because I have to pass them to the other part of the code for other purpose.

Comment: @ ForEveR can you please Explain them on the code? I will Edit the question

Comment: @ForEveR, When I call my function I know that I receive a vector which has been constructed such that there would be a combination of various "a, q" and "a, b, b". then I have two functions which gets as input "a, q" and "q, b, b".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not need to split the vector into different vectors:

```
auto rngq = boost::adaptors::filter( vec, 
    []( boost::variant<T1, T2, T3> const& v ) {
        return v.which()==boost::variant<T1, T2, T3>::type<T3>::index;
    }); // rngq is now a range over type T3
```

Now you can iterate over `rngq` and calculate the vector index:

```
boost::for_each(rngq, [](boost::variant<T1, T2, T3> const& t3) {
    // The standard guarantees that the vector elements 
    // are put into sequential memory
    ptrdiff_t index = &t3 - &vec[0]; 
});
```

If you want to split the elements into separate vectors for some reason, you can use the same trick as long as you split them into separate `std::vector< boost::variant<T1,T2,T3>*>`. This solution of course requires that you keep the original vector `vec` around.

All of this is not particularly beautiful, but it is up to you to judge if there is maybe a better solution to your problem.

I don't think there is a solution if you really copy the elements into a different vector each. When the original vector is not sorted, linear search is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks but when I try to implement your solution, I receive some errors. I am wondering If you tested your answer.

Comment: I fixed a typo. It is not C++98 obviously. It uses lambdas that you'd need to replace with functors. What is the error you get?